# Why this Golang code could leak value of variable which is in memory

Tags: go, memory, slice

This code could leak the value of the variable which is in memory.

I think maybe the `fmt.XprintY` doesn't reset the buffer, but my attempt at debugging is fruitless.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "text/template"
)

type SecWriter struct {
    w io.Writer
}

func (s *SecWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    fmt.Println(string(p), len(p), cap(p))

    // here
    tmp := fmt.Sprintln("info{SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS}")
    if tmp == ""{}

    s.w.Write(p[:64])
    return 64, nil
}

func index() {
    exp := "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA{{1}}"

    b := &bytes.Buffer{}
    s := &SecWriter{
        w: b,
    }


    t := template.Must(template.New("index").Parse(exp))
    t.Execute(s, nil)

    fmt.Println("buf: ", b.String())
}

func main() {
    index()
}
```

My `go env`:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOOS=windows
```

go version

```
go version go1.12.5 windows/amd64
```

And the output is:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 64 64
1 1 128
buf: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1nfo{SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS}                 AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

As you can see, part of the value of the variable in memory:

```
tmp := fmt.Sprintln("info{SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS}")
```

Leaks to the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no memory leak**, [this](https://play.golang.org/p/y2GrscBpOEh) proves it.
But there is an [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34720): The call to `p := newPrinter()` initialized here `p.fmt.init(&p.buf)` in `func Fprint(w io.Writer, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)` returns the free memory (underlying array of a slice) without initializing it to zero (which is not initialized probably for performance reasons - **which we expected to be all zero**).

TL;DR:
Two solutions:
1. Workaround: Use `s.w.Write(p)` instead of `s.w.Write(p[:64])`, or edit your code and set `p[len(p):cap(p)]` all to zero (if you don't or cannot touch the 2nd solution):

```
func (s *SecWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    b := p[len(p):cap(p)]
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = 0
    }
    fmt.Println(string(p), len(p), cap(p))
    // here
    tmp := fmt.Sprintln("info{SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS}")
    if tmp == "" {
    }
    s.w.Write(p[:64])
    return 64, nil
}
```

---

2. In Windows (`C:\Go\src\fmt\format.go`) or Linux (`/usr/local/go/src/fmt/format.go`) file at line 58 set the buffer to all zero:

```
    b := (*buf)[:cap(*buf)]
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = 0
    }
```

Inside this function:

```
func (f *fmt) init(buf *buffer) {
    b := (*buf)[:cap(*buf)]
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = 0
    }
    f.buf = buf
    f.clearflags()
}
```

Your code output with this applied:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 64 64
1 1 128
buf:  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1
```

---

Long answer:
You're watching the slice data beyond the assigned length, and you are allowed to see the slice data to the slice capacity.
You may replace: `m.Writer.Write(p[:8])` with: `m.Writer.Write(p)` which makes your code works correctly. The following code shows that `template.Parse()` tokenizes the template to 3 parts and calls `my.Write()` three times. the interesting part here is the **second** call to the `my.Write()` shows a compiler-generated slice with different slice capacity which is not initialized to zero, "maybe this is a minor harmless [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34720)":

If you want to spy on your computer's memory, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/HOeK23IkZBN):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    my := &myWriter{"You", buf}
    template.Must(template.New("my").Parse("Hi{{.Name}}Bye.")).Execute(my, my)
    fmt.Printf("<<%q>>\n", buf.String())
}
func (m *myWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%v cap=%v\t%v %v\n", len(p), cap(p), string(p), p[:cap(p)])
    no++
    fmt.Println("gen:", no, gen())
    m.Writer.Write(p)
    // m.Writer.Write(p[:8])
    return 8, nil
}

type myWriter struct {
    Name string
    io.Writer
}

const genLen = 8

func gen() string {
    b := [genLen]byte{}
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = no
    }
    return string(b[:])
}

var no = byte(49) //'1'
```

Output:

```
len=2 cap=8 Hi [72 105 0 0 0 0 0 0]
gen: 50 22222222
len=3 cap=64    You [89 111 117 58 32 53 48 32 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 10 50 32 49 48 53 32 48 32 48 32 48 32 48 32 48 32 48 93 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
gen: 51 33333333
len=4 cap=8 Bye. [66 121 101 46 0 0 0 0]
gen: 52 44444444
<<"HiYouBye.">>
```

And change `const genLen = 64` try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/d1O2D1tsEqQ)
**intersting**: the `cap=64` changes to `cap=128` (which is not expected):

Output:

```
len=2 cap=8 Hi [72 105 0 0 0 0 0 0]
gen: 50 2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
len=3 cap=128   You [89 111 117 58 32 53 48 32 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
gen: 51 3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
len=4 cap=8 Bye. [66 121 101 46 0 0 0 0]
gen: 52 4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
<<"HiYouBye.">>
```

---

The `t.Execute(my, my)` calls `func (m *myWriter) Write(p []byte)` so the `p` with `len=3` and `cap=128` generated by the tamplate engine.

After debugging the 2nd code inside `/usr/local/go/src/fmt/print.go` file at line 230, it seems it is `fmt.buffer` with `length=3`, and `cap=128`, here:

```
func Fprint(w io.Writer, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    p := newPrinter()
    p.doPrint(a)
    n, err = w.Write(p.buf)
    p.free()
    return
}
```

The call to `p := newPrinter()` initialized here `p.fmt.init(&p.buf)`:

```
// newPrinter allocates a new pp struct or grabs a cached one.
func newPrinter() *pp {
    p := ppFree.Get().(*pp)
    p.panicking = false
    p.erroring = false
    p.wrapErrs = false
    p.fmt.init(&p.buf)
    return p
}
```

Gets and returns the free memory without initializing it to zero.

Comment: I know the tamplate engine will recognize "Hi{{.Name}}Bye" to `TextNode, ActionNode, TextNode`, and will write 3 times. But, in your code, in the second time writing: the `[]byte("50 22222222")` is in the local variable `p`, and it was **written into stdout** in last loop. So I don't think it's because of the slice used by the template that's not initialized.

Comment: The `t.Execute(my, my)` calls `func (m *myWriter) Write(p []byte)` so the `p` with `len=3` and `cap=128` generated by the tamplate engine.

Comment: See the Solution, and try it yourself and let me know. Your code output with the solution: `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 64 64
1 1 128
buf:  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get back to you in time. Thank you for your efforts! So if I understand correctly: on the 1st invoke of `myWriter.Write`, fmt.Sprint set the buffer to "info{SSSSS}", then on the 2nd invoke, fmt.printer get the cache from `ppFree sync.Pool` and not set the buffer all to byte(0). But there is still something that confuses me: 1. if I  invoke fmt.Sprintln in the function `index` instead of `Write`(https://play.golang.org/p/u6jJDaBHfk5), the memory in fmt.buffer is not leaked; 2. why the memory in fmt.buffer is readed in a local variable `p []byte` generated by template engine?

Comment: The `"info{SSSSS}"` in your code `tmp := fmt.Sprintln("info{SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS}")` or ` fmt.Println("gen:", no, gen())` in my code is the function call parameters which, compiler puts to the stack (as expected) to call the function `fmt.Sprintln()` or my code `fmt.Println()`  so when the function call is done (return from that function) the stack (memory) footprint is there (without any problem) and the next memory for the new slice takes it and use it (it is OK), but we expected that the new slice initilized to zero (which is not initialized probably for performance reasons).

Comment: oh you mean the memory of local variable `"info{SSSSSSSSS}"` on stack is used by the new slice before the GC collects it, and the memory is reused by `fmt.ppFree sync.Pool` without initilizing to '0'. I think this can explain this issue. And it is caused by overreading, probably more like an UB

Comment: Yes. exactly. Normally this is not a problem. Because we use `Write(p)` not `Write(p[:cap(p)]` and we may use `Read(p[:cap(p)]` and this is OK.

Answer (score 2):

In Go, the expression `s.w.Write(p[:64])` can expand the slice beyond its length without an error (till the slice's capacity). In this case the provided buffer's length is only 1, but you expanded it to 64 (as in the second line of your output). The content in the extra 63 bytes is undefined, and it happens to be the output of some `fmt` methods.

The solution is to check the slice's length. If you want to make the slice foolproof and ensure it's impossible to see the content beyond its length, you can use the three index syntax for slices to set its capacity, such as `p = p[::len(p)]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign to the variable directly instead of doing `fmt.Sprintln`, the variable will not leak.

Code: https://play.golang.org/p/Nz0y_MfDjP1

So I believe `fmt.Sprintln` is causing the leak. This function calls a another unexported function `newPrinter` to get a `printer` which in turn maintains it's own pool and caches. I haven't gone deep enough but my guess would be somehow the buffer you created manually might be getting overlapped / shared here somehow.

(I will update the answer if I find anything else)

Comment: I tried to run without `Sprintln` and it seemed to have removed the `"info{SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS}"` part from the output. 

https://play.golang.org/p/Nz0y_MfDjP1

Comment: yes, so i think it's about XprintY functions' buffer. And while using `fmt.Println` to print into stdout, the value is also leaked. https://play.golang.org/p/cmMwp6Tidnr. Seems that only `printer.buf` will share the memory with the local variable `p[:64]`